# Why does this string of LTR and RTL markers cause Android devices to 'hang'?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, crashes

I received this innocent-looking message forwarded from my brother on Whatsapp claiming that it could 'hang' my phone.

[image: Original Message]

And sure enough... touching it would make my Android Samsung J2 running Android 6 freeze over for a while; it would ask me if I wanted to force close the app or wait.

I suspected there was more than met the eye here and copied the message over to my laptop and pasted it on an editor and opened the file through python and this is the string that I get from python. Turns out whoever is doing this is using/misusing the Unicode `\u200e` left-to-right, `\u200f` right-to-left, and `\u2067` 'right-to-left-isolate' character interspersed with some spaces to do this mischief. All the apps I've tried are falling victim to this tiny prank.

Below is the message in its Unicode hex format:-

```
"\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f \u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u200e\u200f\u2067 ereh-hcuot-t'nod"
```

Questions:

1. What does this string actually cause text editing programs to do? Make them go left and right too many times?
2. Why does this cause Android apps to 'hang' or crash?
3. Going off reports from my friends, this problem doesn't seem to affect iPhones. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tom Scott did an interesting video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jC4NNUYIIdM)

Fundamentally, the fact that it is triggered by touching the text probably means it's a bug in the code responsible for working out which part of the text is highlighted (which is not at all trivial in Unicode) so it can be copied/pasted or otherwise manipulated. Given it hangs, it is possible there is an exponential blowup or infinite loop in the algorithm due to the many LTR/RTL transitions. I'm not aware of any detailed analysis of the source code and bug, though one may appear from the android team at some point.

iPhones have a completely different set of text rendering and interface libraries, so they will likely use a different algorithm here, or at least one which suffers from a different set of bugs.